# Disable automatic wsdl publication on JBoss (EAP6)

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, wsdl

By default, most application servers automatically generate a WSDL if a client accesses http://somehost.com/someservice?wsdl. My goal is to disable this feature on JBoss EAP6. This is not about why this should be (or should not) be done but about the how.

Here's what I've already tried:

- Using a urlrewrite configured in JBoss as described in https://community.jboss.org/thread/223243. Unfortunately, I was unable to make it work as the proposed pattern seems to match any request. My guess is that it is a bug because the pattern looks correct to me.
- Using an web app urlrewriter (Tuckey urlrewrite) does not work because the request is intercepted by JBoss before it is processed by the urlrewriter filter.
- In Weblogic there is an explicit feature to enable or disable automatic WSDL generation (see docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webserv_ref/dd.html) but I was unable to find something similar for JBoss.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used in standalone.xml:

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
  <alias name="localhost"/>
  <rewrite pattern="(.*)" substitution="-" flags="F">
    <condition test="%{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="wsdl"  flags="OR,NC"/>
  </rewrite>
</virtual-server>
```